# Something like Spring's VelocityEngineUtils that can use URL to template

Tags: spring, email, velocity

I'm using Spring and Velocity templates to send emails. The new request is that the templates are no longer stored locally, but fetched from an external service. VelocityEngineUtils expects a relative path to the template, but all I now have is an URL. While I'm aware that I can fetch and save the template locally before calling VelocityEngineUtils, I'm asking if there already is something in Spring that can help (as it often happens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what velocity resourceloader you are using at the moment? I assume that you are using **ClasspathResourceLoader**?

If you need to get velocity template from an external service through a URL, you can specify the resource loader to `org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader`

Comment: This is the correct answer, although it wasn't all that easy to find how to exactly implement it. I found an example here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?57560-velocity-and-URLResourceLoader-trouble